# How to setup a scheduled task to run every 30 minutes? Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003

I'm having a problem running a scheduled task in Windows 2003 server, it ran for 4 hours, now it won't start up again.

I will tell you exactly what I have done to create the task, please tell me if I am doing anything wrong.

My objective is to have my task (console app) run every 30 minutes.

1. I open control panel, scheduled tasks, add new scheduled task
2. Browse for my application I want to run, a console app without any command line arguments
3. I select, perform this task - Daily
4. I select the start time (now 8:00 in the morning)
5. Start date set to today
6. Set the correct username + password
7. Open advanced properties
8. Repeat the task every 30 minutes for 24 hours

Save and close.

Anything wrong in the above mentioned steps I've implemented?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your configuration steps are correct... what is in the log? C:\Windows\Schedlgu.txt

A good place to start might be at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308558